# Is it possible to host MapServer in the cloud, specifically in Azure?

Tags: mapserver, cloud-gis

Can MapServer be hosted in the cloud?

I presume as a virtual machine, or is it possible to have it as an Azure Web App, and avoid the hassle of VM maintenance

And by cloud, I mean Microsoft ... *but if I put Azure, my question gets flagged as a duplicate of my question about hosting GeoServer in Azure*

Comment: If you mean http://mapserver.org/ it is not Java.

Comment: MapServer doesn't need a JRE, it's not a Java application.  Azure doesn't imply Windows, you can set up Linux servers in Azure, and   Yes, I've previously had MapServer on a Linux server on Azure. So I guess that's a half an answer.  I don't see any reason why you couldn't install MapServer on Windows with Azure though.

Comment: @nmtoken Thanks for the clarification on JRE ... my bad, I'd just copied over the question from my GeoServer one. But is it possible to go all the way to a Azure Web App and avoid having to manage yet another virtual machine?

Comment: what about https://www.mapserverpro.com/? [not affiliated with them]

Comment: interesting what @nmtoken expalined. If I use a linux server and put there mapserver et al, this would replace my private server (eg. at home) right? but this azure server allows me to get my gis app online? static ip is not an issue anymore?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely host mapserver in azure. Here's a blog post detailing the installation process on a virtual machine. I do not get into configuring mapserver, just how to install it on a virtual machine.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/javiersantana/2017/01/25/hosting-mapserver-in-a-microsoft-azure-virtual-machine-windows-and-linux/

Regarding the azure web app; you might be able to get this done by running php on an azure web app and including the mapserv cgi binary. I'll update this answer once I'm done testing.

*****UPDATE 2/1/2017*****

Getting mapserver to work on an azure web app requires that you copy the binaries over. You can do this via the kudu console or you can connect via ftp. Create a handler mapping under application settings in the azure portal.
[image: handler mappings]

Then navigate to the url to test .azurewebsites.net/cgi-bin/mapserv

I hope this helps.